# Javascript - Packaging audio and graphics files

Tags: javascript, loading

I'm porting a game to Javascript that contains ~80 little sound effects and graphics. To reduce traffic, I would like to bundle all of these files into one.

As far as I've been able to find, there is no native support for Javascript accessing files from archives.

I'm thinking of creating a single large js file containing everything in base64 encoded data.

Are there any other/better/standard approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can load all the graphics/image files in the form of sprites and atlases